# facebook Graph API error 200 : App Does not have a permission to post to target

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

please help !

please look at this pic

[image]

i have this error when i upload a video to graph-video API from facebook, how that can be happen? i have search that on google and i found this topic not exists in anywhere, anyone know how to solve it ? please help me. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for editing aS,k

Comment: I'm using permissions publish_stream and manage_pages and I have same problem like you. Until yesterday it worked well. What permissions are you using?

Comment: you can see in that URL which i posted in pic , i have included almost ALL permissions

Comment: Are you uploading to a page, or to the user's videos? If you are uploading to a page you will need an access token specific to that page available via https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

Comment: thanks at last i found a problem, this is a bug!

Answer (score 0):

in the last i found this problem is a bug

check it out

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221714001339683